# Why do the values of my hashes never match in Java?

Tags: java

I have a `.jsp` which accepts password input.  It will not match the hash of a password inside the application, even though a test using `attempt.equals(password)` works prior to the hashing.

I am passing the string thus:

```
PasswordManager.checkPassword(request.getParameter("password"))
```

This is my hashing code:

```
byte[] password = p.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] attempt = a.getBytes("UTF-8");

passwordHash = DigestUtils.md5(password);
attemptHash = DigestUtils.md5(attempt);
```

In addition, I have set the encoding in the `.jsp`:

```
<fmt:requestEncoding value="UTF-8" />
```

However, the hashes remain stubbornly different.  Any ideas?

Comment: Different how? Are the actual bytes different? Or the references you get back from DigestUtils? (Latter question is a loaded one.)

Comment: Isn't your password already stored as an MD5 hash? I think you only want to hash the attempt and then compare it to the already hashed password.

Comment: If I do a `println` with `.toString()` on the hash of (theoretically correct) input, I get: `[B@7452ba3a` and `[B@6340717f`, where the first is the password and the second is the "correct" input.  I will store the password as an MD5 hash soon; this is an experiment.

Comment: What you're getting as the output of `toString()` isn't an MD5 hash…

Comment: Okay, that's bizarre.  Changing the `md5()` to `md5hex()` fixed it. What I was getting before is supposed to be a `byte[]` array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those values suggest to me that perhaps toString() isn't overloaded.  Are you calling toString on the byte arrays?  If yes, those are the hash codes of two different objects.

Try this:

```
byte[] password = p.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] attempt = a.getBytes("UTF-8");

passwordHash = DigestUtils.md5(password);
attemptHash = DigestUtils.md5(attempt);

System.out.println(new String(passwordHash));
System.out.println(new String(attemptHash));
```

See if they are the same values this way.

Comment: Nope, you're not an idiot.  Sometimes it's possible to look at a problem too long.  You just need someone to break you out of a rut.